# Android Library unsatisfied link error with jar file

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have one project that includes a `sample app`, and a module that we'll call the `sdk` that I created that I will eventually package up as an `.aar` file when all is complete. The `sample app` tells the `sdk` to run a service. This service requires the use of external libraries that have been packaged as a `.jar` file that includes `.so` files. The issue is that every time I try to load the libraries, I get an unsatisfied link error saying that the `.so` file does not exist and therefore cannot open the library. I'm not quite sure if I'm placing everything in the right place as the error says. If I am missing a step, I was hoping someone could help point me towards the right direction. Below I'll show the file structure of my project as well as what I'm doing to try to open the library.

**File Structure**

```
`- MY PROJECT
     - My Sample App  (com.mine.mysampleapp)
           - build
           - src...etc
     - SDK (separate module) (com.mine.mysamplesdk)
           - build
           - libs
                - my-lib.jar
                     - assets
                          - arm64-v8a
                               - my-lib.so
                          - armeabi-v7a
                               - my-lib.so
```

**Library Loading Code**

```
System.load(context.getFilesDir() + "/my-lib.so");
```

What I'm not understanding is that the `.so` file lives inside the `sdk` but the error message:

`dlopen failed: library "/data/user/0/com.mine.mysampleapp/files/my-lib.so" not found`

shows that it's looking for the file in my sample application.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to package as an AAR, those have built in support for JNI libraries: https://www.codepool.biz/build-so-aar-android-studio.html

Rather than putting the libraries in the assets directory and trying to assemble the `System.load` path yourself, put them in that directory and then you can just `System.loadLibrary("my-lib")` (note that `System.loadLibrary` won't actually let you open a library that isn't prefixed with "lib", so you need to rename your library for this to work).

Comment: Did you mean unpacking the `.jar` then using the `.so` files into a `jniLibs` folder?

Comment: If so, I think the issue with this is that I'm trying to access a very old library that was built to be used as a `.jar`. The native methods have a different package name from my app so it can't map it out the right way unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Given that it's "my" lib, I assume you built that jar? Can't you fix it?